# I need a formula or script that duplicates and works with new copies of the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I have made a set of sheets to be character sheets for D&D games.  On my first character page "Vaegon", I used a section for spells but wanted to be able to use either Mage spells or Priest spells.  I made a section of drop downs for each level of spells and then made a drop down toggle basically to switch between them.  I have a formula in cell A2 of the "Validation" sheet to link it to the toggle R1 on the Vaegon sheet.  Problem is I need to be able to make duplicates of the Vaegon sheet and rename them for new characters and I need the spells section to work with the new pages as well, but of course right now they will only work with the page called Vaegon.

Is there a way to write the formula so that it works with duplicate and renamed pages or would it have to be done with a script somehow instead of a regular drop down.  I have linked the sheets so you can look at it and see how it might be fixed.  All the character sheets have to remain on the same spreadsheet so I can't just make a copy of the whole spreadsheet and then update the name in the formula.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-dl5LDiZgJkn2Q99J_wEdt2KL_MQBu1jhoD8w-45qEk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this, can't you just manually duplicate and rename the sheet? Consider providing more details about `I need the spells section to work with the new pages as well`.

Comment: The point is to make things faster and easier.  I can duplicate and rename the sheet manually but since the sheet links to the validation sheet by name, I also then have to duplicate and rename the validation sheet as well and then go into the new character sheet and redo the data validation to link it to the sheet.  If I need to do 6 or 7 character sheets, this becomes a lot of time and work.  That is why I am looking for a solution that will make it function but also update on it's own with new copies of the sheet.

Comment: I had a similar issue earlier on this project.  I had a field set up to add experience points where you type it in and hit enter and it adds the amount to your total and then clears the field for the next entry.  At first it would only work with the original sheet because the script called it by name.  Someone helped to change the script so that when I made duplicates the script would check for the sheet name instead of having the name built into it.  I am hoping for something similar here but since 2 sheets are involved it seems more difficult if it's possible.

Comment: Hi, consider specifying clearly what settings/cells have to be changed when duplicating a sheet (where are the cells located, where are the new names coming from, etc.). As it's currently written, I think your question is insufficiently clear, and you're unlikely to get a proper answer.

Comment: The original named sheet is called Vaegon.  Cell R1 on Vaegon links to a validation page called Validation.  R1 links to A2 on the Validation page with this:                    =if( Vaegon!R1 = "Mage", 
   { 'Mage Spells'!A2:I }, 
 if( Vaegon!R1 = "Priest", 
   { 'Priest Spells'!A2:G }, 
   na() ) )                                                                                                                                What is links to is 2 different pages of spells, Mage Spells and Priest Spells.

Comment: In order to copy the character sheet for a new player, I have to copy both Vaegon and Validation, change the name of each to for instance Agaron and Agaron Validation, then change the link in A2 of Agaron Validation to have the name Agaron instead of Vaegon and then go back to the new Agaron page and redo the Data Validation on the 9 columns that actually display the info from the Spells pages. What I am hoping for is either a different way to accomplish the links to the spell pages that duplicates when you copy a page, or possibly a script that would automate the process I described.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution:

- Duplicate the source sheet via [Sheet.copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet).
- On the new sheet, replace all the instances of the original character name with the new one, using [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder).
- Create a new sheet for Validation of the new character, using [Spreadsheet.insertSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname) (alternatively, you could duplicate the older `Validation` sheet using `copyTo`.
- Add the desired formula to the new validation sheet, using, [Range.setFormula](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula), dynamically interpolating the new sheet name instead of the old one.

#### Code sample:

```
function duplicateSheet(sourceName = "Vaegon", targetName = "New character name") {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceName);
  const targetSheet = sourceSheet.copyTo(ss).setName(targetName);
  targetSheet.createTextFinder(sourceName).replaceAllWith(targetName);
  const targetValidation = ss.insertSheet(`Validation ${targetName}`);
  targetValidation.getRange("A1").setFontWeight('bold').setValue("Validation");
  targetValidation.getRange("A2").setFormula(`=if( '${targetName}'!R1 = "Mage", 
   { 'Mage Spells'!A2:I }, 
 if( '${targetName}'!R1 = "Priest", 
   { 'Priest Spells'!A2:G }, 
   na() ) ) `)
}
```

#### Note:

I assume you want to have a different `Validation` sheet for each character. I don't think it makes much sense trying to have all this in a single sheet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I got help from another source and we used a script to dynamically generate the drop down columns and no longer needed to have the validation pages at all.